# React navigation transition animations with useNativeDriver only run first time

Tags: animation, react-native, react-navigation

I am using `react-navigation` `Transitioner` to create a custom `StackNavigator`. When using `useNativeDriver: true` in my transition configuration, the animation for the transition only runs the first time. When set to false, it works as expected.

> Note: Whilst setting it to `false` does fix my problem, I get choppy performance on Android without it, even in production mode.

Below snippet is my navigation view

```js
render() {
    return (
        <Transitioner
            configureTransition={this._configureTransition}
            navigation={this.props.navigation}
            render={this._render}
        />
    );
}

_configureTransition = () => {
    return { useNativeDriver: true };
}

_render = (transitionProps) => {
    return transitionProps.scenes.map(scene => this._renderScene(transitionProps, scene));
}

_renderScene = (transitionProps, scene) => {
    const { layout, position } = transitionProps;
    const { index } = scene;

    const translateX = position.interpolate({
        inputRange: [index - 1, index, index + 1],
        outputRange: [layout.initWidth, 0, 0],
    });

    const animationStyle = {
        position: 'absolute',
        width: '100%',
        height: '100%',
        backgroundColor: '#FFF',
        transform: [{ translateX }],
    };

    const Scene = this.props.router.getComponentForRouteName(scene.route.routeName);

    return (
        <Animated.View key={scene.key} style={animationStyle}>
            <Scene />
        </Animated.View>
    );
}
```

Below is a screen cap of the problem. Note how the first transition is animated, whilst future ones are not (the 'back' navigation should be animated too)

[image: Screen cap of issue from iOS simulator]